# CSS Disabled style

Tags: css, internet-explorer, web

I'm trying to change the style of a `disabled input` using IE5 only.

I tried the `[disabled]`, `:disabled` and `[disabled=disabled]` but not one is working.

HTML INPUT:

```
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="Button " id="ctl08_ctl02__wizard__btnPrevious" value="Back" onfocus="try{document.getElementById('__LASTFOCUS').value=this.id}catch(e) {}" name="ctl08$ctl02$_wizard$_btnPrevious">
```

Is there something I can do about that ?

Comment: where are your code ??

Comment: Attribute selectors are supported by [IE7 or higher](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). Why are you using IE5? I think only javascript will help you in this case.

Comment: So there is nothing I can do about that ? No IE5 hacks ?

Comment: If you can only modify CSS, you have no chance. If you could add a js library you would have a chance with [this IE7 library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ie7-js/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<input type="text" name="text_1" disabled="disabled">
```

Check , if it is working or not.

Or do it with **JavaScript** as well.

Comment: The OP wants to change the default style of disabled input tag, your answer doesn't solve that

Comment: Not working with this input too, I can't add javascript, CSS is the only thing I can modify at the moment

Comment: @Abdou ... You can try this, too. `input[type="submit"]:disabled { // your CSS } `

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 5 doesn't support disabled attribute. The default color for IE is Grey. But the style of the disabled attribute supports in all other browsers but not in IE5.

As @Huelfe said in comments, The disabled attribute styles are supported in IE7 and higher only, which can be given like :

```
input[type="text"][disabled] {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I wish I could use a higher version of IE, but a the moment I am stuck with IE5 and I need a solution with this :(